# Fill dropdown list from xml with linq

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, drop-down-menu

i have the following xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dropdowns>

  <dropdown name="DropDownLoc">
    <menu text="Select" value="-1" />
    <menu text="North" value="1200" />
    <menu text="South" value="1400" />  
  </dropdown>

  <dropdown nome="DropDownEsp">
    <menu text="Select" value="-1" />
    <menu text="Est" value="7" />
    <menu text="Ovest" value="9" />
  </dropdown>
</dropdowns>
```

I want to read this xml and fill two dropdowns with a method given the dropdownlist name (like "DropDownEsp")
I want to accomplish this with linq, who can help me please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which problems have encountered either LINQ-to-xml or dynamic drop down opulation?

Answer (score 1):

Below is code which would help you read XML and create a list of items (`ListItem`):

```cs
// or use XDocument.Parse("xml string") to parse string
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\testxml.xml");
var dropLists = xdoc.Descendants("dropdown")
                .Select(d => d.Descendants("menu").Select(m =>
                        new /* new ListItem(text, value) */
                        {
                            Text = m.Attribute("text"),
                            Value = m.Attribute("value")
                        }))
                .ToList();
```

Try adding items into controls yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an empty `<asp:DropDownList ID="DynamicDropDown" runat="server" />` control on your .aspx page, you can data bind it a the results of a LINQ query like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
  {
    // Assuming your XML file is in the App_Data folder in the root of your website
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DropDowns.xml");

    // Let's say we want to use the options from the second <dropdown>-tag in your XML
    string whichDropDown = "DropDownEsp";

    // This is the LINQ query to find those options from the XML
    // and turn them into ListItem objects
    var query = 
      from dropDown in XDocument.Load(path).Descendants("dropdown")
      where dropDown.Attribute("name").Value == whichDropDown

      from name in dropDown.Descendants("name")
      let text = name.Attribute("text").value
      let value = name.Attribute("value").value 

      select new ListItem(text, value);

    // Now we data bind the query result to the control
    DynamicDropDown.DataSource = query;
    DynamicDropDown.DataBind();
  }
}
```

In the LINQ query we first select only the `<dropdown>` element with the right name (based on the `whichDropDown` variable). Then we select all the `<name>` elements, and from each one we put the attributes in the `text` and `value` values. Then we use these values to create a new `ListItem` (one is created for each `<name>` element).

This result can then be used to data bind the `<asp:DropDownList>` control.